# Bluetooth not working in Linux

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have windows and linux on my machine. I have bluetooth working on my windows OS but cannot even start in the linux OS. I have tried lots of solutions and drivers but bluetooth cant work still.

Comment: If your Ubuntu really is 14.04 as the tag you gave suggests you may need an upgrade for better hardware support. The Bluetooth stack really changed a lot in the last 5 releases from 14.04. Try with a live system of a recent release.

Comment: Could you please post the outputs of: `dmesg | grep -i blue` and `sudo lshw | grep -i blue`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: On running dmesg | grep -i blue, i get:[20342.636325] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[20342.636365] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[20342.636372] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[20342.636378] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[20342.636389] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[20396.591638] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[20396.591642] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[20396.591646] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

Comment: and on running sudo lshw | grep -i blue i get =====>description: Bluetooth
                product: RT3290 Bluetooth

Comment: Pilot6 :  01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
 DeviceName: Ralink WLAN Ralink RT3290LE Roma 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi + BT4.0 co
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
 Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci